# What does "el=str ns" mean on a 500 Internal Server Error Log?

Tags: python, server, request, python-requests, http-status-code-500

I am sending a SOAP Request to a server and get on the client side the error "500 Internal Server Error" and as a server log the error text "Unexpected element -el=str ns-" on the method "Deserialize_Header".

I can not find anything related to this errors. Any help is welcome.